# The target Flash Player version 11.1.0.0 specified should be equal or higher than the minimum version 23.0.0.0 required by Flex SDK

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder, flash

I am getting this error when trying to build an AdobeAir project.
I have an extension.xml file with this line:

```
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/4.0">
```

I tried to change it to 23.0 in the end, but it didn't help.

The error appeared after upgrading Air SDK from version 18 to 23.

> The target Flash Player version 11.1.0.0 specified should be equal or
>   higher than the minimum version 23.0.0.0 required by Flex SDK

There is no place where 11.1.0.0 is mentioned

Answer (score 0):

In your descriptor file (the one that ends in .xml), change the second line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/23.0">
```

It has to start with application, not with extension.

But, something is odd with the message, it indicates Flash Player instead of AIR.
You might want to change the compiler settings as well.

- In Flash Builder, create or open a new project.
- Open the project Properties panel (right-click and chose 'Properties').
- Select Flex Compiler from the list on the left.
- Add "-swf-version=34" to the 'Additional compiler arguments' field.

I have copied and adjusted the instructions from the [Flash Player 23 Release Notes](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_23_air_23_release_notes.html)

Answer (score 0):

There should be a descriptor file where you can define `target-player` version. I'm using **IntelliJ** as an **IDE** where it creates `MyProjectName.iml` and defines `target-player` version as below:

```
<configuration name="MyProjectName" target-platform="Desktop" main-class="Main" output-file="Main.swf" output-folder="$MODULE_DIR$/out/production/MyProjectName">
    <dependencies target-player="23.0">
      <sdk name="AIR SDK 23.0" />
    </dependencies>
</configuration>
```